# Show $X=\{n \in \mathbb{N}: \text{n is odd and} \ n = k(k+1) \text{for some} \ k \in \mathbb{N}\}=\emptyset$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

Show $X=\{n \in \mathbb{N}: \text{n is odd and} \ n = k(k+1) \text{for some} \ k \in \mathbb{N}\}=\emptyset$

My proof is as follow, please point if I have made any mistake.

**proof:**

we have $\emptyset \subseteq X$
suppose $X≠\emptyset$  pick $n \in X$

Then there are 2 cases
1st case: n is odd then n=(k+1)k

Then 
suppose k is odd $\implies$ k+1 is even $\implies$ n is even

2nd case: consider k is even $\implies k+1$ is odd

then 
n=(k+1)k for some $k \in \mathbb{N}=\emptyset \implies n$ is even

Therefore, n is neither even nor odd, so $k \in \mathbb{N} \implies n \not\in X$
and $\implies X= \emptyset$

Q.E.D

Comment: The two cases should start a line later, and it's "$n$ odd **and** $n=k(k+1)$", not **then**

Comment: Other short proofs: $k(k+1)=2 \cdot(1+2+\cdots+k)$ is twice an integer, thus even. Or: $k(k+1) = (k+1)^2 - (k+1)$ but a number and its square have the same parity, so the difference between them is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct, I would just be a bit pedantic about your format and ordering. So I'll follow on from your proof:

Suppose for contradiction that $X\neq \emptyset$ and pick $n\in X$

Then we know $n$ is odd and we can write $n=k(k+1)$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Then the two cases are:

$(i)\quad k\equiv 0\bmod 2\implies n\equiv 0\bmod 2\implies n\not\in X$

$(ii)\,\,\,\,k\equiv 1\bmod 2\implies k+1\equiv 0\bmod 2\implies n\equiv 0\bmod 2\implies n\not\in X$

Therefore by exhaustion of the all the possible cases, we have arrived at a contradiction, and hence $X=\emptyset$.

It's exactly the same as what you did, but just a bit neater (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

An even shorter proof (not that yours is wrong):

One of $k, k+1$ must be even, therefore so is the product $k(k+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combinatorial proof that $k(k+1)$ is always even for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. The number of two element subsets of a $k+1$ element set is 
$$
\binom{k+1}{2}=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$
as there are $k+1$ choices for the first element of the subset and $k$ choices for the second element of the subset, but as $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,a\}$ represent the same set, we divide the product by $2$ to find the number of such subsets. The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a very long-winded approach.

Your $X$ can be expressed as:

$$X=\{n\in\mathbb N|\text{n is odd} \land \text{n is even}\}$$

and we need to prove $X=\emptyset$.